# Android onSelectedItemListener with a ListView CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE

Tags: android, events, listview

I am a novice on Android developpement and I need some help.

Before i start with my question, thank you for your help.

Ok, here is my problem:

I have a listView with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE enabled.
With this, i can select some elements on my listView.

I would like to use an item selection as an Event in my code, for exemple, when the item is selected, i would like to display a toast (Item "Name of Item" Selected).

I don't know how to do this, i have read something about the onSelectedItemListener but I don't know how to implement and use it.

Thank you again for all your help.

Here is the solution for this problem: I made a list with the selected items. To see which itel is selected, i have to test if the id of this item is it the list. If insside, the item is selected, if not, the item is not selected.

```
listeCapteurs.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    if (!mSelectedIndices.contains(position))
        {
        mSelectedIndices.add(position);
        System.out.println("Liste:" +mSelectedIndices );
        }
    else
        {mSelectedIndices.remove((Integer)position);
        System.out.println("Liste:" +mSelectedIndices );
        }
        Log.i(null, "Clicked item position = " + position );       
}});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you had a read through the ['Hello ListView demo'](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html)? It demonstrates how to use the `OnItemClickListener`. Now, that might not be exactly what you're after, but from an implementation point of view, adding an `OnItemSelectedListener` is identical:

```
listview.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Edits as per comments below.

You could try explicitly setting the selection to a specific item after populating the list to see if that triggers OnItemSelected. Assuming you have at least two items in your list:

```
listview.setSelection(1); // select second item
```

//Edit2: Actually, this will probably not make a difference, reading the [documentation for setSelection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setSelection%28int%29).

> Sets the currently selected item. **If in touch mode, the item will not
>   be selected** but it will still be positioned appropriately. (...)

Alternatively you can keep track of the selected items yourself using the OnItemClickListener, assuming there's no other action upon clicking an item - which makes sense on devices with only a touch screen, as there is no way to differentiate between a 'selection' and 'click'.

```
List<Integer> mSelectedIndices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//...
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        if (!mSelectedIndices.contains(position)) {
            mSelectedIndices.add(position);
        } else {
            mSelectedIndices.remove((Integer)position);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that at some point you want to do something with the selected items, so then you can just iterate over above list and grab the objects that were clicked/selected.

Comment: Dear MH.,


Thank youvery much for your answer. The solution given by coder_For_Life22 is working, but as you said, i need the `OnItemSlectedListener` and i can't implement it.

When I only change the `OnItemClickListener` by the `OnItemSelectedListener`, the second one does not work.

I have tryed to put a `System.out.println("hello");` and it works with the `OnItemClickListener` but nothing hapens with the `OnItemSelectedListener`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I can't implement it" and "does not work"? I'm not a 100% sure this method works when using touch interaction. What happens when you explicitly call `setSelection(...)`? Alternatively you can just keep a list of clicked/selected items using the OnItemClickListener: simply add an item (or at least the index) if it isn't in the list of clicked items yet, otherwise remove it.

Comment: Thank you again for your help.
To be more precise, i can implement this method, but when i select one item from my listview, nothing happens, my println is not executed.
When I call setSelection(...), hmmm, what is this?
I am afraid I don't understand the method with adding the index, can you please give me more details???

Comment: I added some code to illustrate the basic idea of what I mentioned in above comment.

Comment: Oh, thank you, this is an great idea.

In which concern the SetPositio(), nothing happens when I am doing this explicitely.

In which concern the table, yes I ned to know which item was selected and then to do something with this.

I have a litle problem with this code: 
`!mSelectedIndices.contains(position) ? mSelectedIndices.add(position) : mSelectedIndices.remove((Integer)position);`

I don't understand it and Eclipse give me some errors.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I guess i have to do this:

`if (!mSelectedIndices.contains(position))
   {
   mSelectedIndices.add(position);
   }
  else
   {mSelectedIndices.remove((Integer)position);
   }`

Comment: Great Great Great, 

Thank you so much MH., this works.
Thank's to you, i am able to continue with my program.


Have a nice day,

Milos.

Comment: Doh, that was my dumb mistake. Of course, the shorthand notation only works for assignments/return statements. `boolean b = !mSelectedIndices.contains(position) ? mSelectedIndices.add(position) : mSelectedIndices.remove((Integer)position);` would've worked, but I should've just written it as in your last comment. Sorry about that. You were correct. I'll correct it in my answer. If it's what you're after, please consider marking it as the answer. Good luck with further development.

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like this..

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {

  // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

});

Comment: Hi coder_For_Life22, thank you so much for your answer.
Your solution works fine, but i need to know the item i selected and not only clicked on it.

Can you propose me another solution please?

Thank you..

Comment: So you need to know like the ID of the row? example..Row 1,2,3,4

Comment: I have found the solution, thank you so much for your help, this forum is so good...